# Venue cannot run specials

Tags: foursquare

I am creating a special using Foursquare as a page but is unable to create it on all venues across page with error "Venue cannot run specials".

Answer (score 0):

Not all categories of venues can run specials; e.g. homes and offices can not run specials.

Comment: I have ran many specials in this venue already before the new FOursquare changes.

Comment: Then you'll need to offer more details about your problem -- you current question doesn't give anyone much to work with.